# File attributes does not exist in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

There is no equivalent of [Window's file attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Linux ?

Comment: please comment a negative mark

Comment: Vague question, no prior homework done.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but it does seem appropriate, since this question a) does not demonstrate any research effort, and b) is vague to the point of meaninglessness, which is what some of the windows attributes would be under linux (so of course no, there is not an equivalent for *all* of them, if that's what you are asking).

Comment: FWIW, I didn't downvote you, but the reasons must be those above.

Comment: Is there a particular attribute you're interested in? See, e.g., `man chattr`. Some of those Windows ones map over, some don't; some map to extended attributes, etc.

Comment: I did made some homework (only found out about file permissions). I also google-it but found nothing. Thanks for man chattr. A good starting point

Comment: Also look at ACLs (`getfacl(1)`, `acl(7)`). If digging deeper, SELinux contexts are also relevant... so, no, Windows attributes don't exist in Linux; there is a much, much richer set of permissions available.

Comment: Of course Linux has file attributes too, but they're different ones. Which attribute are you interested it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read the [Linux extended attributes man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/attr) or see [Extended File Attributes Rock!](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/8741/) from Linux magazine. A more technical introduction that hints at the differences between Linux ACL's and extended attributes can be found in ht t p://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online

Linux extended attributes are a more general framework that allows arbitrary attribute definition.

Samba provides a mapping between Linux extended attributes and Windows file attributes for ACL's as shown in this article ht t p://pig.made-it.com/samba-file-rights.html#11775.